# Can ImageButton cause an unresolved R?

Tags: android, imagebutton

Tried to create an app with a few ImageButtons which will play sounds. As the images I added to drawable folder were pretty big, thought they were causing trouble; so tested with launcher images but same error emerged. Fed up with this nagging trouble..  Please suggest an way out..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:background="null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the error that you are facing

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your background property. you can not provide "null" value into your background property.

Please try

```
android:background="@null"
```

It might help you.

Comment: I added the background property but error doesn't disperse. Can the size of a image instigate such error?

Comment: Yes, It's ok but as your above xml is working fine with the use of _android:background="@null"_. And you are still getting the same error. So if possible share your activity and mipmap resources. It will be helpful to find the solution.